# Inventory-system for Text-RPG - global bug

Tags: python, inventory, global

RPG-inventory doesn't work good. I'm sorry if my code too bad, I just started to learn Python.

Python 3.7.0

IDLE 3.6. (64-bit)

Sublime Text 3.1.1.(3176)

```
#firstly I created classes for items and items_in_body_parts.
#for example, one of them:
class item_for_put_on:
    def __init__(self):
    self.name = ''
    self.body_part = '' #for what body part? like in Diablo, for example, you can take a weapon in your hand and put on a helmet on your head
#there is a lot of other staff, i deleted it to make it simple, here are the main things:
right_hand_item_1 = right_hand_item() 
on_head_item_1 = on_head_item() 
item_for_put_on_1 = item_for_put_on() 
item_check_on = item_check_on_class() 
right_hand_item_1.name = ''
right_hand_item_1.body_part = ''
on_head_item_1.name = ''
on_head_item_1.body_part = ''
item_for_put_on_1.name = ''
item_check_on.name = ''
i_stick = ['Stick', 'in_hands']
i_helmet = ['Helmet', 'on_head']
all_item_names = {'Stick' : i_stick, 'Helmet' : i_helmet}

def item_put_on():
    global item_for_put_on_1, right_hand_item_1, on_head_item_1
    if item_for_put_on_1.body_part == 'on_head' and on_head_item_1.name == '':
        on_head_item_1.name = item_for_put_on_1.name
        #go back to function inventory_menu
    if item_for_put_on_1.body_part == 'in_hands'and right_hand_item_1.name == '':
        right_hand_item_1.name = item_for_put_on_1.name
        #go back to function inventory_menu

#def inventory_menu(): --- this and a lot of other functions i don't decribe you, it's not necessary

def inventory_bag():
    #we come here from inventory menu to see what we have in the bag
    #global item_check_on, item_for_put_on_1 ---- should be globals here?
    #here was some code - to describe to player all content of the bag - it works good
    #NOW PLAYER DECIDES WHAT ITEM TO CHOOSE TO READ INFO ABOUT IT AND AFTER THAT HE CAN PUT IT ON HIS HERO
    #command4 - it is the list of items.names in bag - it works good; player should type full name or to choose item's number
    com4 = input ("> ")
    while com4 not in commands4 and com4.lower() != 'back':
        print ("Unknown command, try again.\n")
        com4 = input ("> ")
    if com4 in commands4: 
        ppp = com4
        for i in all_item_names: #i - str!!!
            if ppp == all_item_names[i][0]: 
                item_check_on.name = all_item_names[i][0]
                item_check_on.body_part = all_item_names[i][1]
                # remember ---- i_stick = ['Stick', 'in_hands']
                # remember ---- i_helmet = ['Helmet', 'on_head']
                # remember ---- all_item_names = {'Stick' : i_stick, 'Helmet' : i_helmet}
                print("You are looking to the item " + item_check_on.name) #this is just info to display for player
                print("item body part: " + item_check_on.body_part) #this is just info to display for player
                ppp = ''
                com4=''
                print ("Would you like to 'equip'('eq') it or 'back'?\n")
                com5 = input ("> ")
                commands5 = ['back', 'equip', 'eq']
                while com5.lower() not in commands5:
                    print ("Unknown command, try again.\n")
                    com5 = input ("> ") 
                if com5.lower() == 'back':
                    inventory_bag()
                    break
                elif com5.lower() in ['equip', 'eq']:
                    item_for_put_on_1.name = all_item_names[i][0]
                    item_for_put_on_1.body_part = all_item_names[i][1]
                    item_put_on()
                    break
                break
            else: 
                print('test looping') #loop while going to this again and again, searching for the correct name of item in dictionary all_item_names
                if ppp == '' and action4 == '':
                    break
    elif action4.lower() == 'back':
        #inventory_menu()

def inventory_eq():
    #we come here from inventory menu to see what is equipped on our hero
    #global right_hand_item_1, on_head_item_1 ---- should be globals here?
    print("right arm - " + str(right_hand_item_1.name) + "\n")
    print("head - " + str(on_head_item_1.name) + "\n")
    #SO HERE WE CAN SEE WRONG INFO --- if you put on only one thing, everything is right, but if you put on the second thing - there will be two sticks (one on head, one in hand) or two helmets (one on head, one in hand)
```

SO HERE WE CAN SEE WRONG INFO: if you put on only one thing, everything is right, but if you put on the second thing - there will be two sticks (one on head, one in hand) or two helmets (one on head, one in hand); because of problems with names of items. And if I add more items and body-slots for them, and the last one will be for example Shield - there will be many shields on the hero's body instead of right items. And there are no previous items in inventory, of course.

In my opinion, the problem is somewhere with global variebles or maybe while-loop somewhere is not working good (maybe assigning every second forever, i don't know).

It seems that when we change item_for_put_on_1 it changes everything, that was assigned it - on_head_item_1 and right_hand_item_1 in function item_put_on().

And if i use clearing function for item_for_put_on_1 (to make it ='') in item_put_on() after item was equipped - it somehow deletes items' names from equipment

So the main problem is connected with item_for_put_on_1, but i need help to find a way to fix it.

Comment: Edit your Question accrodingly to [mcve].

Comment: On StackOverflow, the [rpg tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rpg) tag refers to the [RPG language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_RPG) used primarily on IBM midrange systems [IBM i](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_i).  However, this question probably belongs on [Game Developmemt](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, deleting objects and object.names. Now I use simple variables - I made them global everywhere.

Now it is works! But I don't understand what was the problem, even if we replace stupid unnecessary "item_for_put_on_1" by direct name from dictionary "all_item_names[i][0]". The problem wasn't solved with this method. The below code still didn't worked (the same problem with changing names)

```
# item_left_hand, item_on_head - these are objects, they got .name firstly

# below code is in item_put_on(): #I also saved global i from inventory_bag() for that
if all_item_names[i][1] == 'in hands':
    item_left_hand.name = all_item_names[i][0]
elif all_item_names[i][1] == 'on head':
    item_on_head.name = all_item_names[i][0]
```

But usual global variables (not objects) work very good:

```
global item_left_hand, item_on_head #in all functions

# below code is in item_put_on(): #I also saved global i from inventory_bag() for that
if all_item_names[i][1] == 'in hands':
    item_left_hand = all_item_names[i][0]
elif all_item_names[i][1] == 'on head':
    item_on_head = all_item_names[i][0]
```